# Why does extraction of gzipped sitemap fail in Scrapy 0.24.4?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am getting the "Not a gzipped file" exception while retrieving a gzipped sitemap xml (tested on amazon.de)

According to the bugtrackers, there used to be a bug regarding "Not a gzipped file"

I am using Python 2.7.3 and Scrapy 0.24.4

Can anyone confirm this as a bug or am I overseeing something?

**UPDATE**

I think this is some valuable information, already posted on github as well

**Possible bug:**
retrieving a gzipped sitemap xml (tested on amazon.de) fails.

**Reproduce with:**

1. modify /utils/gz.py gunzip method to write the incoming data to a file.
2. gunzip the file on the command line.
3. the unzipped file contains garbled content
4. gunzip that file with garbled content a second time and get the correct content

I suspect that the content coming from the target server is already gzip compressed and scrapy has a bug that causes the gzip http decompression to not work properly, resulting in a double compressed file arriving at the  /utils/gz.py gunzip method

Comment: Why don't you ask the developers? They would probably thank you for a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Pablo Hoffman is around here frequently

Comment: [Raymond Hettinger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) drops in too, but I'd still raise any Python issue at http://bugs.python.org/ ! Either way, it's hard to diagnose an issue with so little information.

Comment: I raised it in githubs bugtracker for the scrapy repo. do you think this is a python related bug?

Comment: Sorry, no; I mean *if I had a suspected Python bug*, I would raise it in Python's bugtracker. If you have already raised this in `scrapy`'s GitHub, perhaps you should wait for a response there?

Comment: yepp. will do. what else could help to track it down with regards to additional information?

Comment: Well, it's always helpful to provide a short example of code and any associated data that recreates the issue. There's a good (if sarky!) guide here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: found the bug. in branch 0.24 

line 25 in the httpcompression middleware
states
if content_encoding and not is_gzipped(response):

this needs to be
if content_encoding and is_gzipped(response):